# display data from an array in json form

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

i got an array from echo $posts

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 14
                [name] => اسطنبوليه
            )
    )
```

i have this array (part of the main array)and now i wish to convert it to json form. however i am not able to do so, i tried to convert the data through

```
echo json_encode ($posts);
```

but instead of original data i am getting an output `u0627u0633u0637u0646u0628u0648u0644u064au0647n`

can anyone tell how i can get the correct form

Comment: May have to do with UTF-8

Comment: This is what I got when testing your array http://codepad.viper-7.com/8ULGm0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try echo json_encode($posts,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE) (php 5.4 and above)

Answer (score 0):

2 things. Firstly view source of the output in the browser and you should see it as a JSON encoded string rather than the interpreted version.

Secondly it looks like there is some character encoding issues as the string you're getting back is unicode. Make sure you have the encoding set right on your server and browser.